# Object does not contain a definition for Title

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller that passes data to my view through the ViewBag

My controller:

```
var aJobs = from a in gdb.AcceptedJobs
            where a.Job.EmployerID == (Guid)Session["UserID"] && !a.Archived
            select new { a.Job.Title, a.Job.Address };
ViewBag.jobs = aJobs;
return View("Employer");
```

My view:

```
foreach (var job in ViewBag.jobs)
{
    @job.Title
    @job.Address
}
```

Now, when i browse to the page i get error `object does not contain a definition for Title`, at `@job.Title`, why is this?

I'm using ASP.Net MVC3 C#

Answer (score 2):

Try creating your anonymous type this way

```
select new { Title = a.Job.Title, Address = a.Job.Address };
```

Answer (score 0):

When im debugging, and the error is thrown i checked the locals. Then i can clearly see that in the first iteration, the job-object contains a Title-string with the value of my name.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.